# Extract jQuery UI menu element and jump to each image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript

[image]

(My code is also here: http://jsbin.com/urupig/4/edit

**"Next"** and **"Previous"** button is working but **"Jump"** button does not work.)

Hello, I am newbie of JavaScript and CoffeeScript.

I want to extract **"Jump"** element and want to **jump to each image** from jQuery UI menu.

Below code uses Flickr API for image. At first, Ajax communication was done and the URLs of images was loaded.

I want to jump each image but when children of "Jump" element was clicked, "index is out of number" was written in console.

HTML:

```
<body>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="next">Next</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="previous">Previous</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="jump">Jump</a>
        <ul id="jump_ul">
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<br />
<div id="images"></div>
</body>
```

CoffeeScript:

```
class PhotoTable2
  json: null
  number: null

  constructor:(number) ->
    @number = number

  getData:(successCallback) =>
    $.getJSON(
      'http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?jsoncallback=?'
        format : 'json'
        method : 'flickr.photos.search'
        api_key : '7965a8bc5a2a88908e8321f3f56c80ea'
        user_id : '29242822@N00'
        per_page : @number
      (data) =>
        @json = data.photos.photo;
        successCallback?())

  url:(index) ->
    item = @json[index]
    itemFarm = item.farm
    itemServer = item.server
    itemID = item.id
    itemSecret = item.secret
    itemPathList =
      'http://farm' + itemFarm + '.static.flickr.com/' + itemServer +
      '/' + itemID + '_' + itemSecret + '_m.jpg'

  putPhoto:(index) ->
    if (0 <= index and index <= (@number - 1))
      $('#images').empty()
      $('#images').append(
        $('<h3></h3>')
          .text(@json[index].title)
        $('<a></a>')
          .append(
            $('<img />')
              .attr('src', @url(index))))
    else
      console.log('index is out of number')

    console.log('index: ', index)

$ ->
  index = 0

  photo_table2 = new PhotoTable2(5)
  photo_table2.getData(successCallback = ->
    console.log('Data loaded',photo_table2.json)

    photo_table2.putPhoto(index)

    $('#next')
      .click ->
        index++
        photo_table2.putPhoto(index)

    $('#previous')
      .click ->
        index--
        photo_table2.putPhoto(index)

    for i in [0..(photo_table2.number - 1)]
      $('#jump_ul').append(
        $('<li></li>').append(
          $('<a></a>')
            .text(photo_table2.json[i].title)
            .click ->
              photo_table2.putPhoto(i)
            console.log(i)
        )
      )

    $("#menu").menu()
  )
```

Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having the standard "closure in a loop problem". You'll notice that `console.log('index: ', index)` always says `5`; that's because the click handlers end up sharing one reference to the same `i` and the value of that `i` will be the final value that `i` had in the `for i in [0..(photo_table2.number - 1)]` loop.

The standard solution is to wrap the loop body in a self-executing function to force `i` to be evaluated when you want it to be. CoffeeScript provides [`do`](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) (see the bottom of that section) specifically for this purpose:

```
for i in [0..(photo_table2.number - 1)]
  do (i) ->
    # Continue as before
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/urupig/5/edit